# How to connect to a remote bindshell with forwarding port

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, exploit, metasploit

I am trying to solve buffer oveflow challenges provided by my school. 
There is a c program on the server exposed as a service on some port e.g. lets say  2323

Also they have provided bindshell port e.g 2525 and they have mentioned that they rely on TCP-bindshell on guestport 4444. i.e. 2525 is redirected to port  4444 on my virtual machine.

---

I am writing an exploit using metasploit, but I don't really understand the concept here of bindshell provided to me.

I tried netcat from my machine to server IP on 2525 it says:

```
root@comp:/tmp# nc -nv [Server IP] 2525

(UNKNOWN) [Server IP] 2525 (?) open

root@comp:/tmp#
```

as you see it opens but does not listen continuously.

While running exploit I am using RPORT as 2323 but I don't understand where should I mention bindshell port 2525

Does anyone have any idea of how should I proceed. How do I connect to shell on port 2525 which directly is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you might want a reverse shell?

The idea in metasploit's exploit is, when your target machine is cracked, they are trying to send the shell back to 'your machine' instead of you trying to connect to them.

So, what we normally do is, open the listening on your main machine and wait for the connection back.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Here do you mean that I should start listening on 4444 as :   nc -lvp 4444  and then execute the exploit

Comment: @TechJ According to what mostly other exploits are doing, yes. but I am not sure how your exploit suppose to work in which way, all based on your decision.